# Approval and expiry date

Tags: patent-lifetime, patent-pending, ep2298800a1

Has patent EP2298800A1 been approved and if so, what is the expiry date?

Answer (score -1):

As per EPO register patent is under examination.

https://register.epo.org/application?number=EP10014361&tab=main

Comment: I wasn't the down-voter, in fact I just happened randomly across this post now, but a better answer might explain how you found this. For instance, did you go to Google Patents or another similar tool, and if so, how would someone else do that? Did you read the application number and know off-hand, and if so, how might another user read a number like that and know? It's good practice to teach the asker how to find out the answer on questions like this themselves.